# Why is Hikari Datasource leaking in this situation?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hikaricp

I use the Spring Framework (with JPA). The id in the URL was parsed to dynamically create and use a Datasource. Datasource used caffeine to cache, but it was not released from memory even after the expiration time. This caused a memory leak. After the expiration time, it is removed from the cache, but it is not released from memory. Memory leaks occurred even if the cache was removed to allow the Datasource to be used once. Is there any way to cache Datasource?

Below is part of the code.

```
    private HikariDataSource getDataSourceRdsLocation(RdsLocationEntity rdsLocationEntity){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setAllowPoolSuspension(true);
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://"+rdsLocationEntity.getServerReadOnly()+"/"+rdsLocationEntity.getDatabaseName());
        config.setUsername("");
        config.setPassword("");

        config.setPoolName(rdsLocationEntity.getName());
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setMinimumIdle(1);
        config.setIdleTimeout(3600000);
        config.setMaxLifetime(7200000);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(500);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

```
new CaffeineCache(cache.getCacheName(), Caffeine.newBuilder().recordStats()
                                .removalListener((key, value, cause) -> {
                                    if (cause.wasEvicted() && value instanceof HikariDataSource ds) {
                                        ds.close();
                                    }
                                })
                                .expireAfterWrite(cache.getExpiredAfter(), cache.getTimeUnit())
                                .maximumSize(cache.getMaximumSize())
                                .build()
```

Comment: can you please share a reproducer in github ?

Comment: Like @ozkanpakdil, I also suggest to share Github repo to reproduce a problem. Also, what measurements / observations you did to conclude that it was a memory leak?

Comment: Even if you call close of HikariDataSource, the object still remains in the thread local. I found it through the result of taking a heap dump using jprofiler. This thread local seems to be created to manage the HikariDataSource, but I haven't been able to find a way to directly access it or release the object from it.

Answer (score 0):

for i in {1..1000}; do jmap -histo:live pid > out3.log ; grep org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManage out3.log; date;/bin/sleep 5; done >log5.txt | tail -f log5.txt

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!